# Removing numbers from the initial position of a string in SQL server

Tags: sql

Is there any functions available in sql server for removing the numbers from a string only if there are at the initial positions. For example, if we have data like '1234ab4c' or '56def7' or '8gh', it should return ab4c or def7 or gh.

In oracle, we can use regex for removing it. I am not finding any option in sql server.

Can someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stuff()` and `patindex()`:

```
select stuff(col, 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%', col) - 1, '')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dbc06e7df81d40a473498dd48ea671cc) is a db<>fiddle.